# Trouble uploading large files to tomcat with spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have an application to upload video files to my server but last attempt to load a 4GB video file and upload the file came only 368Mb total of 4GB.

This is the code of the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("idClient") String idClient,
        @RequestParam("idChannel") String idChannel, @RequestParam("idPlayList") String idPlayList,
        MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
    MultipartFile file = null;

    while (itr.hasNext()) {

        file = request.getFile(itr.next());

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {

            sb.setLength(0);

            sb.append(tmpFolder).append(idClient).append("_").append(idChannel).append("_").append(idPlayList)
                    .append("_").append(file.getOriginalFilename());

            try {

                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(new File(sb.toString())));

                stream.write(bytes);

                stream.close();

                response.add("File " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " uploading.");

            } catch (IOException e) {

                response.add("File " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " not upload.");

            }

        } else {

            response.add("File no subido " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " file is empty ! .");

        }

    }

    return response;
}
```

That will be happening?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Have you ruled out tomcat config is the problem?  http://tecadmin.net/increase-tomcat-upload-file-size-limit/

Comment: It has not worked put parameters but still receives only 368Mb of 4GB but does not send me any errors not only the total file copy.

Comment: Can you post the portion of your tomcat web.xml that contains the <max-file-size> node?  Make sure the value has been entered in bytes, so for 4 GB if I'm not led astray by the internet would be 4294967296.  If Tomcat is running 32 bit, that will be the limit.  If Tomcat runs out of disk space, I'm not sure if you would get an error.... just an after thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved! Thank you
The problem is that when you load a file over 2GB surpasses the maximum size of an array of bytes can support is for this reason that the file did not come completely to solve this creates a buffer that reads the file into blocks or chunks.

```
public void copyPartsBufferFile(InputStream input, Integer bufferSize, String fullPathDetiny) {

BufferedOutputStream stream = null;

    try {

        stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(fullPathDetiny)));

        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(input);
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
        byte[] bytes;

        while (rbc.read(buffer) >= 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            bytes = buffer.array();
            stream.write(bytes);
            buffer.clear();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {

    }

}
```

I leave my code in case someone happens the same!.

Regards.